# Dividing integers Scenario

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example of integers $a$ and $b$ in which $a$ divides $b^2$ but does not divide $b$.

I am not sure if this applies to a special set of integers. Taking regular integers I cannot think of anything that would satisfy this statement.

Comment: What is a "regular integer"?

Comment: Just like 1,2,3.... could be abstract like a combination of integers or something.

Comment: Is a combination of integers ever not an integer?

Comment: Then what would be a nonregular integer?

Comment: obviously an integer that in not regular.... just kidding. sorry that wasn't a mathematically correct statement.

Answer (score 3):

If you took $a=4$, could you find such a $b$?

Comment: b=2..... gotcha. sorry Idk how i missed that one. too late for me I guess.